# Unusual KeyError when formatting HTML

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a class that takes an arbitrary HTML template and `str.format()`s it for a specific use case. For instance:

```
<h1>Hi, {userName}!</h1>
<p> It's {weather} today.</p>
```

would become:

```
<h1>Hi, Jon Skeet!</h1>
<p>It's sunny today.</p>
```

To do this, I have a `Template` class:

```
class Template:
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        templateDirectory = getTemplateDirectory()  # we don't need to worry about this
        with open(os.path.join(templateDirectory, "templates", name + ".html")) as templateFile:  # we get the template we need
            self.template = templateFile.read()

        print(self.template)  # all in order: we get the un-formatted HTML 
        print(kwargs)  # all in order: we get a dict of things to replace (i.e. {'userName': 'Jon Skeet', 'weather': 'sunny'} )

        self.final = self.template.format(**kwargs)  # this should just replace things nicely, but it doesn't: why?

    def __str__(self):
        return self.final
```

I instantiate like this:

```
ErrorTemplate = Template('foo', var1=42, var2='foo')
print(str(ErrorTemplate))
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file.py", line 11, in <module>
    ErrorTemplate = Template('foo', var1=42, var2='bar')
  File "/path/to/the/file/with/Template/class.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.final = self.template.format(**kwargs)
KeyError: 'document'
```

I'm not using 'document' anywhere. I have no idea where it gets 'document' from. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you instantiate your object? Sounds like you're passing a `document` keyword argument to the constructor which is not defined in your template.

Comment: Can you post the actual template that results in the stated error?

Comment: @zwer https://pastebin.com/yW9wnnfc

Comment: Can you flesh out your example to show how you create a `Template` object?

Comment: `{document.write("unknown")} ` This javascript code is being formatted by `format()`.

Comment: @TheoC - `{document.write("unknown")}`  <-- that's what is causing it. You need to escape your curly braces (i.e. `{{document.write("unknown")}}`) so that `str.format()` doesn't attempt to evaluate them.

Comment: @zwer Oh, I see. Silly me, should have thought of that. Thanks!